The walls in this house might have concrete inside of them, how would i mount large tvs , my pole mounted monitors and run cables thru where i need?
This house was moved from a southern state , not sure what one in 1969, owner says it was built in 1901,the owner is unfortunately one of those guys that destroys almost everything he touches, definitely not up to code, and super smoked out- at best- worst ... I don't know. My husband and i just moved in and had tried to drill thru a interior wall to run some cables, and the hole started smoking and we couldn't Get thru, all indicators say it is concrete, as does the owner, which would mean that it is drywall, wood frame , concrete ,and whatever layers are outside?  Is it possible to mount our TVs on any wall if it is like that? Or my pole mount for my 3 screens and the tray for my laptop/keyboard? This house is insane it has a 4 foot crawlspace under the house  .. And no foundation its crazy,  also it is so very hot , I'm in northern Cali and its about 114-109 daily rite now , and it feels like a sauna,   there is so much work that needs to be done but that's not my job , I would like to try to replace all the windows since not a single one actually fits where it is put, and hopefully that will help keep the cool air in, but as a temp fix what is the least expensive way besides the windows  that I could try to seal in this room from heat, bugs ? The parts that has hard wood only , if under the house with a flashlight , someone inside can see the light shine thru , other parts they had laid down linoleum and then tile ,  roof  is absolute shit too , apparently they just use a heavy duty tarp and extra strength floor adhesive to keep it in place , but hey , 600 a month for a large 3 bedroom house ,that feels like a pirate ship in some rooms cause the floor is bowing ... Its an adventure ... Rite ?

Please, edit your post to limit it to one question and include some judicious returns and punctuation to make it readable. Right now your post is more of a screed than a question. I find it hard to believe that the interior walls of a house are concrete but if they are the answer to the question in the title of your post, is a hammer-drill with concrete anchors, and yes you could mount everything that way and it would be much stronger that any wood constructed home. This is how it is normally done in industrial construction.

it is difficult to believe that a concrete structure was moved from one state to another

how is the 4 foot crawlspace relevant to the question about drilling a hole in the wall? ... or the temperature, or the windows?  ... your post is 90% irrelevant filler
